# Display timeout error in UI if api response takes longer

Tags: reactjs, axios

In my react application, while doing the api call I would like to check if the response takes more than 60 secs to hit, I should display some error message - "Request Timed Out" .

I am using axios in my application for http calls.

```js
axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: 'http://localhost:8765/fetchData',
      timeout: 60*1000
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      data: requestData
    })
      .then(response => {
        if(condition1){
          history.push('/validated');
        }
        else if(somecondition2){
          history.push('/not-validated');
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

I am setting the timeout before headers as per the axios documentation but I am not sure how to add the check to display the error message and how should I validate this.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code that handle Timeout

```
...
this.state = {
 error:''
}
...
    axios.get('api/fetchData',{timeout:10}
                        )
                .then((res)=>{
        console.log(res)
    }).catch((e)=>{ 
        if(e.code == 'ECONNABORTED'){
            console.log('you can now handle time out here')
            this.setState({error:"Request Time out."})
        }
    })
...
return (
 <div>
   ...
   {this.state.errror?this.state.error:''}
   ...
 </div>
)
...
```

Your code can do the same by little changes.

```
axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: 'http://localhost:8765/fetchData',
      timeout: 60*1000
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      data: requestData
    })
      .then(response => {
        if(condition1){
          history.push('/validated');
        }
        else if(somecondition2){
          history.push('/not-validated');
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
         if(error.code == 'ECONNABORTED'){
            console.log('you can now handle time out here')
            this.setState({error:'Request time out'})
        }
        console.log(error);
      });
...
return(
 <div>
   ...
   {this.state.error?this.state.error:''}
   ...
 </div>
)
```

I have timeout value 10 millisec because.I run that on local server.
Hope this help